# Sources to learn about Greens functions

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

For a physics major, what are the best books/references on Greens functions for self-studying?

My mathematical background is on the level of Mathematical Methods in the physical sciences by Mary Boas.

Comment: You should be more specific. There are Green's functions which are general linear kernels, and more specific uses in quantum mechanics, where the Greens' function is the energy representation of the propagator.

Comment: http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=14090033
http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=14090034
http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=14090035
http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=14090036

Comment: For the love of all that is good pedagogy, you should first make sure you understand the equivalent of a Green function in a *finite* vector space, i.e. with matrices. If you do this, everything else will be incredibly obvious.

Comment: @DanielSank, what do you mean by "equivalent of a Green function in a finite vector space, i.e. with matrices"?  Matrix <=> differential operator and G <=> M^{-1}?

Comment: @bernander Yes, more or less.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to refer to Jackson's 'Classical Electrodynamics' for several examples of solutions using Green functions. I also found chapter 7 of 'Mathematics for classical and quantum physics' by Byron and Fuller quite helpful. Its title itself is 'Green functions'.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

---

- http://math.arizona.edu/~lega/583/Fall98/lectnotes/GF1.html
- http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node49.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r317iUJfAeI
- http://www.phys.washington.edu/users/baker/green.pdf
- http://physics.ucsc.edu/~peter/250/gf.pdf
- http://academicearth.org/lectures/delta-function-and-greens-function
- Sommerfeld.  The sixth volume of his physics series is 
  pure maths, PDE's of Physics and is a wonderful physicists' view of
  the maths.